# Ethernet Cable Through Floor

Tags: wiring, low-voltage, ethernet

I'm trying to add an ethernet drop to an entertainment center. The coax cable drop was drilled through the floor (picture), since the room below is an unfinished basement with easy ceiling access. Is this code compliant? Would it be code compliant to add the ethernet cable next to it? Or do we need to drill up into the wall?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how much code applies to low-voltage wires. Since it's unlikely this will be inspected at any point in the near future, I'm not sure it much matters.

You can drop Ethernet or coax through a drilled hole like this. Mind you, it's not sightly, but it sounds like that it's not a concern. It would be trivial to remove, since you simply remove whatever ends you've attached and pull the wire back into the basement.

If you have access into the wall, the cleanest solution would be to drill through the top plate of the basement and the bottom plate of the wall, then cut a low voltage bracket in and fish the wire up.

Comment: And if you decide to use @Machavity's advice to fish the line through the wall, you might as well pull the coax cable back down and feed it up through the wall as well.  Will be minimal extra work, and look a lot better to boot.