# How do I run ethernet [or other low-voltage wire] at an exterior wall?

Tags: walls, joists, ethernet, low-voltage

### Is there anything different about adding an outlet to an exterior wall?

I've added several ethernet jacks to interior walls (drywall) using low-voltage rings & keystone plates, but never on an OUTSIDE wall.   I'm familiar with the techniques discussed here:

- [How do I run ethernet, speaker wire, and coax through a wall into a crawlspace?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1234/how-do-i-run-ethernet-speaker-wire-and-coax-through-a-wall-into-a-crawlspace/)
- [Ethernet Cable Through Floor](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/188837/ethernet-cable-through-floor)

Should I be worried that the bottom plate of my wall is inaccessible from the open basement, due to the rim joist?

The following diagram (cleaned up from [ornl.gov](https://foundationhandbook.ornl.gov/handbook/section2-1.shtml)) seems to show that I might have a drill path (red) to add a outlet plate (green arrow).

Is the best way to drill UPWARDS at the red arrow after finding the location by drilling DOWNWARDS at the blue arrow?  Or what's the best way?

[image: Wall cross-section with arrows]

Comment: what does the basement has to do with that ? Where is the outlet location on that drawing

Comment: Does it have to go though all the wood/wall, or can it run on the outside surface of the wall?  Might need two holes from top and bottom, unless you can angle the bit enough.

Comment: The outlet is meant to be cut into the drywall at the GREEN arrow.  

@crip659: In this case, I **can't** use the outside of the wall unfortunately.

Comment: if you have some strong magnets you may not need to drill the blue hole, just feel using the magnet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a cable installer drill bit to drill upward along the red-arrow path. (It would be challenging to drill the path in the downward direction because of the degree of curve/bend you'd have to hold in the drill bit while working.)

The presence of insulation in the wall can make a big difference. It's not too bad if the insulation is fiberglass batt, but if it's something more rigid like rock wool, blown in cellulose, dense blown in fiberglass, etc then it'll be a chore to connect between the sill plate hole and the cutout in the drywall.